# TypeError: datetime64 type does not support sum operations

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[31], line 1
----> 1 df_sale.pivot_table(index='Gender', aggfunc='sum')

Attached is my data frame generated from the google excel sheet.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW9tA.png)

TypeError: datetime64 type does not support sum operations

I was trying to create a pivot table using the pivot_table() method. Then i try displaying the sum of all the numerical columns. But it is throwing and error because of the Date and Time columns (which i bet are being considered as numerical).What is the best solution for this issue?

the command i ran in my jupyter notebook : `df_sale.pivot_table(index='Gender', aggfunc='sum')`

Comment: Please format code and replace picture with data as text. See [ask] for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Simpliest here is aggregate `sum` with `numeric_only=True` parameter:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10)
df_sale = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'a': range(10), 'Gender':list('fffffmmmmm')})  

df = df_sale.groupby('Gender').sum(numeric_only=True)
print (df)
         a
Gender    
f       10
m       35
```

Your solution working if select numeric columns by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) with convert `Gender` column to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), because `Gender` column is non numeric:

```
df = (df_sale.set_index('Gender')
             .select_dtypes(np.number)
             .pivot_table(index='Gender', aggfunc='sum'))
print (df)
         a
Gender    
f       10
m       35
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Is there a way i can exclude the "Date" and "Time" Columns from being displayed on my dataframe while using the pivot_table() method

Comment: @blessedson - sure, use second my solution - `np.number` exclude datetimes and Time columns also with strings columns